# Cannot read property 'undefinedProperty'

Tags: react-native, null, undefined-behavior

I was getting this error
Error Message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefinedProperty' of null"

Tried this and this saved my life!

if (myObject && myObject.undefinedProperty) {

// Access the property here

console.log(myObject.undefinedProperty);

} else {

// Handle the case where the property is not defined

console.log("The 'undefinedProperty' is not available.");

}